# How to create nested arrays based on arrays of strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am trying to create nested arrays with array of strings.
Each string object on the array is delimited by a '|' and that char its uses to create a nested array over an already existing array.

**edit fix** IE: current array

```
var arr = [
    { val : 'root|leaf|lead2|boo|foo|lee'},
    { val : 'root|leaf|lead3|boo|foo|lee'},
    { val : 'root|leaf2|boo'},
    { val : 'root|leaf2|foo'},
    { val : 'root|leaf2|leaf3|more'},
    { val : 'root|leaf2|leaf3|things'},
    { val : 'root|leaf2|leaf3|here'},
    { val : 'sibling|leaf|leaf2|boo'},
    { val : 'sibling|leaf|leaf2|foo'},
    { val : 'sibling|leaf|leaf2|lee'},
    { val : 'sibling|boo'},
    { val : 'sibling|foo'},
    { val : 'sibling|boo|leaf3'},
    { val : 'sibling|boo|leaf3|more'},
    { val : 'sibling|boo|leaf3|things'},
    { val : 'sibling|boo|leaf3|here'},
    { val : 'sibling|ops'},
];

var nested = [
    root = [
        leaf = [
            leaf2 = [
                'boo', 'foo', 'lee'
            ],
            leaf3 = [
                'boo', 'foo', 'lee'
            ]
        ], 
        leaf2 = [
            'boo', 'foo', leaf3 = [
                'more', 'things', 'here'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    sibling = [
        leaf = [
            leaf = [
                leaf2 = [
                    'boo', 'foo', 'lee'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'ops',
        'boo', 'foo', leaf3 = [
            'more', 'things', 'here'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Did you have a look at lodash lib it does exactly what you need

Comment: im not that expert on js, can you try with an example?

Comment: Your example result array doesn't contain valid JavaScript.  Can you fix this please, so we know how to help you, otherwise we'd only be helping you create a JavaScript error and nothing meaningful

Comment: fixed javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here a functional approach, by using `.map()` and `.reduce()` methods. The idea is to parse the path by splitting over the `|` character, and then build the object on the fly.

```
const arr = [
  {cat : 'one|two|thre|boo'},
  {cat : 'one|two|boo|boo|ouch'},
  {cat : 'one|two|thre|boo|lee'},
  {cat : 'one|hey|something|other'},
  {cat : 'one|hey|keys|other'},
  {cat : 'this|blaj|something|other'},
];


function create(array) {
  const parse = elm => elm.cat.split('|');

  const build = (keys, obj, acc) => {
    keys.reduce((a, b) => {
        if (!a[b]) a[b] = {};
        return a[b];
      }, obj);
    Object.assign(acc, obj);
    return acc;
  };

  const obj = {};

  return array
    .map(a => parse(a))
    .reduce((acc, keys) => build(keys, obj, {}), {});
}

console.log(create(arr))
```

You can find the [**Working plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BgQBfOFbehPWTFDsXe00?p=preview)

Comment: can you make it compatible with ECMAScript 5.1 ?

Comment: You just have to replace arrow function by normal function, and replace keyword "const" by "var"